# Use R openssl package hash in a for loop

Tags: r

I am new in R and I try to hash a few columns in my dataset. We are exporting the data to a CSV file and some columns need to be hashed for privacy reasons.

I have it working (the hash) when I use the following statement (with the openssl package).

```
df$field1 <- sha256(df$field1, key=sleutel)
```

It hashes the field1 from the data.frame with sha256. The key (sleutel) is generated a few lines before. This line gives me the result I want.

We have many exports and the fields to be hashed are available in a DB. I can read those fields in a "to_encrypt" variable (class = character).

I want to use them in a for loop but that seems not to work. My for loop is this:

```
for (i in to_encrypt){
   i <- paste("df$",i,sep="")
   i <- sha256(i, key=sleutel)
}
```

I would think this should work. There are no errors but the fields (field1 in this example) is not hashed.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `paste("df$",i,sep="")`, doesn't mean you'll be working with the `df$field1`, `df$field2`, etc column that you want. Instead, extract and reassign the column with `[[`:

```
for (i in to_encrypt){
  df[[i]] <- sha256(df[[i]], key=sleutel)
}
```